# Better update a question, or posting a new one?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4045469/does-a-curve-c-subset-x-that-contains-a-singularity-of-x-pick-up-extra-mult/4045477#4045477) which was helpfully answered. However I realized that this does not really answer my underlying question, and that I might want stronger premises. Now I don't know which option would be better:

1. Updating the question with stronger premises, rendering the correct answer useless. I dislike this, because I would like to show some gratitude towards the answer, as it got me thinking more, so it was helpful and is correct.
2. Accepting the answer, and asking a new question. This might count as spam though?

Comment: Spam means something much more malign than merely asking for further help/clarification.  Spam occurs when you use the site to promote other interests, esp. self-promotion of commercial projects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Someone spent time to read what you wrote, think about it, write an answer. An answer you think is useful.

Don't disrespect them by making their effort an exercise in nothingness. Post a new question with a clarification and a link to the previous one.